I edited an excel workbook all of yesterday while save/save as was greyed out. There is a good chance my licence expired. Can I save my workbook?

Operating system: MacOS Mojave
Excel Version 16.54 (21101001)
Excel belongs to xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx, which is an account from a university which I left 4 years ago

I last saved an excel workbook on July 30. I restarted my laptop yesterday (August 1), and the version of excel seemed to have changed. I edited my workbook all day whilst the save and save as buttons were greyed out, without understanding the underlying problem of why they were greyed out.
I often turn my wifi off when restarting my laptop, so over the last 4 years Microsoft may often have been unable to notify all office programs that the licence had expired. Today I took advice from a computer repairman, and he said (without having run any tests) that the expiry of the license is likely to be the cause of the problem.
My main concern right now is to save the current version of the workbook, in order to avoid having to repeat a lot of work. I plan to buy a cheap excel "scrap licence" from a British seller (I heard there is some legal requirement there tha software needs to be able to sold onwards at least once) and use that going forward.
If I buy a scrap licence, will I need to uninstall and re-install excel in order to make use of it? Does this mean I will be need to end my current session of excel, and that I will be unable to save my workbook?
What about if my "scrap licence" is for a version of excel similar to what I currently have (16.XX)? Would that allow me to avoid having to reinstall the program/ending the current session, and would it allow me to save the very large workbook which I currently have open?
If you think I am likely to lose my current version of the workbook, are there any I workarounds for saving/sharing my workbook in some way before/without buying a scrap licence? (I already tried "sharing" the workbook at File>Share>Share, but it failed because my workbook is saved on my computer rather than in the cloud. I also tried opening it as an email attachment at Share>Send a Copy>Email as Attachment>Right Click on attachment>Save to Downloads Folder, but sadly the only available format seems to be PDF rather than xlsx.)

Click on File > Account. There should be various options like switch license and update license. Having said that, you should just be able to copy/paste to Numbers, or to the web version of excel, or many other options that may not need a license purchase.

Perpetual Office licenses never expire. So do you have Office 365 installed or Office 2021? 16.54 was released in 2021.  So, I am guessing you have a perpetual license. The individual that suggested the license expired is not knowledgeable you have been put down an impossible path (i.e. a perpetual license expiring is not possible). Yes In order to install Office you will have to close all Office application which means closing Excel. "and the version of excel seemed to have changed" - The version you are reporting was release in Oct 2021.

@Ramhound it says in Excel>About Microsoft Excel that I have Version 16.54 (21101001), Licence: Not Activated, Belongs to: yyy@yyy (which is a different account to xxx@xxx from a separate university, where I studied from 2021-2023), © 2021 Microsoft. In the notifications bar under the ribbon it says "View only Your account xxx@xxx doesn't allow editing on a Mac. To learn more, contact your admin about your office plan.", So there do seem to be 2 separate university accounts in play, one (xxx@xxx) presumably from 2012-2020, the other (yyy@yyy) from 2021-2023.

I can also sign into "Microsoft 365" at office.com, where I can edit excel spreadsheets online, but it says I have the Free version and that my Microsoft 365 Personal subscription expired in 2017. (Even though I had access to excel for desktop through my university long after that - I actually don't recall why I should have had a personal subscription at all, unless it was purely necessary to sign up to OneDrive in case that wasn't included in the university package. I doubt I paid anything toward the personal subscription though, since I didn't even know I had one).

The license didn’t expire, the activation status is just linked to the account, unfortunately if you can’t access the account you effectively have lost access to that license. It might seem there is a difference, but details matter, and the spread of information like perpetual licenses expiring is bad

Excel was first installed in October 2019, well before had the account associated with my place of study from 2021-2023 (yyy@yyy). So why did "Belongs to" change from xxx@xxx to yyy@yyy? Could I not change the ownership back to xxx@xxx?

So I installed Excel in 10//2019, whilst still at uni x. Presumably Excel belonged to xxx@xxx at that time = the name of the Microsoft account I'm signed into. Yet ownership of Excel has since changed to yyy@yyy of uni y = the name of a Microsoft account I can't now sign into. (According to file info Excel was modified in 2021, the year of its copyright, which was at the beginning of my studies at uni y.) Would Excel start working again if ownership were reverted back to xxx@xxx? (In that case I could write to Microsoft and ask them to revert the ownership to xxx@xxx.)

Sorry to comment so much and for my wishful thinking, soon I will make a decision about what to buy. I called IT service at University X and they said they didn't think my licence from them (for the 2019 download) would have been in perpetuity. However from @Ramound I understood that Office 2021 would have been in perpetuity. Just for clarity, it is unlikely that I would have paid any money for the licence for Mac. Is there a way to find out what version of Office I had for the 2019 download, and whether that license would have been in perpetuity?
